# How to consume a top-down web service?

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, soap, wsdl

I've been having various issues with a rather complex web service that I've been trying to implement with Eclipse, Tomcat 8, and Axis. This is my first experience with web services so I decided to start messing around with something more simple to make sure that I know what I'm doing. This is the WSDL that I'm currently using to generate a service from in Eclipse.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
 xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/WeatherService/" 
xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
name="WeatherService" 
targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/WeatherService/">
  <wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/WeatherService/">
      <xsd:element name="GetCurrentTemperatureRq">
        <xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="city" type="xsd:string"/>
          </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element name="GetCurrentTemperatureRs">
        <xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="temperature" type="xsd:string"/>
          </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
    </xsd:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="GetCurrentTemperatureRq">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:GetCurrentTemperatureRq" name="parameters"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="GetCurrentTemperatureRs">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:GetCurrentTemperatureRs" name="parameters"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="WeatherServicePortType">
    <wsdl:operation name="GetCurrentTemperature">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:GetCurrentTemperatureRq"/>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:GetCurrentTemperatureRs"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="WeatherServiceSOAP" type="tns:WeatherServicePortType">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="GetCurrentTemperature">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://www.example.org/WeatherService/GetCurrentTemperature"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="WeatherService">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:WeatherServiceSOAP" name="WeatherServiceSOAP">
      <soap:address location="http://localhost:80/WeatherServiceApp/WeatherService"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

This WSDL is not my own and was taken from a [tutorial](https://dzone.com/articles/java-web-service-top-down-approach). I am not strictly following this tutorial as Axis is using wsdl2java for code generation instead of wsimport and I let Eclipse/Axis take care of the web.xml.

I can successfully generate the Web Service and testing using Eclipse's Web Service's Explorer works correctly. My issue is that I want to test this using a generated client instead of just doing it locally to the web service. I generated the web service client and wrote a very simple program inside the client to try and test it.

```
package client;

import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import org.example.www.WeatherService.*;

public class WeatherServiceClient {
    public static void main(String [] args) throws RemoteException {
        WeatherServiceSOAPStub stub = new WeatherServiceSOAPStub();
        GetCurrentTemperatureRq rq = new GetCurrentTemperatureRq();
        stub.getCurrentTemperature(rq);
    }
}
```

Upon running this I get an error.

```
Nov 19, 2019 11:55:05 AM org.apache.axis.utils.JavaUtils isAttachmentSupported
WARNING: Unable to find required classes (javax.activation.DataHandler and javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart). Attachment support is disabled.
Exception in thread "main" AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}Server.NoEndpoint
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: No endpoint
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}exceptionName:org.apache.axis.NoEndPointException
    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:No endpoint
    at org.example.www.WeatherService.WeatherServiceSOAPStub.getCurrentTemperature(WeatherServiceSOAPStub.java:150)
    at client.WeatherServiceClient.main(WeatherServiceClient.java:11)

    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}hostname:fake_hostname

No endpoint
    at org.example.www.WeatherService.WeatherServiceSOAPStub.getCurrentTemperature(WeatherServiceSOAPStub.java:150)
    at client.WeatherServiceClient.main(WeatherServiceClient.java:11)
```

The main web service is running in Tomcat when I try this.

How do I fix this Endpoint issue? Is there a problem in my WSDL with the address or does soapAction need to be changed?

Answer (score 0):

My issue appears to have been with the WSDL or at least how I generated the client. Instead of generating the Web Service and the Web Service Client simultaneously, I instead just generated the Web Service first and deployed it to Tomcat. It seems that Axis generated a slightly different WSDL that worked for my purpose.

So instead of generating the client based off of the original WSDL, I based it off of the WSDL generated by Axis which was at `http://localhost:8080/WeatherService/services/WeatherServiceSOAP?wsdl` in my case.

For those interested, here is the Axis generated WSDL.

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:apachesoap="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" xmlns:impl="http://www.example.org/WeatherService/" xmlns:intf="http://www.example.org/WeatherService/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/WeatherService/">
    <!--
WSDL created by Apache Axis version: 1.4
Built on Apr 22, 2006 (06:55:48 PDT)
-->
    <wsdl:types>
        <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/WeatherService/">
            <element name="GetCurrentTemperatureRq">
                <complexType>
                    <sequence>
                        <element name="city" type="xsd:string" />
                    </sequence>
                </complexType>
            </element>
            <element name="GetCurrentTemperatureRs">
                <complexType>
                    <sequence>
                        <element name="temperature" type="xsd:string" />
                    </sequence>
                </complexType>
            </element>
        </schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="GetCurrentTemperatureResponse">
        <wsdl:part element="impl:GetCurrentTemperatureRs" name="GetCurrentTemperatureRs"></wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="GetCurrentTemperatureRequest">
        <wsdl:part element="impl:GetCurrentTemperatureRq" name="GetCurrentTemperatureRq"></wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="WeatherServicePortType">
        <wsdl:operation name="GetCurrentTemperature" parameterOrder="GetCurrentTemperatureRq">
            <wsdl:input message="impl:GetCurrentTemperatureRequest" name="GetCurrentTemperatureRequest"></wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output message="impl:GetCurrentTemperatureResponse" name="GetCurrentTemperatureResponse"></wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="WeatherServiceSOAPSoapBinding" type="impl:WeatherServicePortType">
        <wsdlsoap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
        <wsdl:operation name="GetCurrentTemperature">
            <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction="http://www.example.org/WeatherService/GetCurrentTemperature" />
            <wsdl:input name="GetCurrentTemperatureRequest">
                <wsdlsoap:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output name="GetCurrentTemperatureResponse">
                <wsdlsoap:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="WeatherService">
        <wsdl:port binding="impl:WeatherServiceSOAPSoapBinding" name="WeatherServiceSOAP">
            <wsdlsoap:address location="http://localhost:8080/WeatherService/services/WeatherServiceSOAP" />
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```